# Mount SMB drive in Xcode using cocoa and objective-c

Tags: xcode, cocoa, netfs

I am trying to build a little app to log into an SMB network drive, but I can't get anything to work for doing the actual connecting. Anyone have any experience with NetFSMountURLAsync? Or even better, an example?

Comment: What have you tried? What was the result and how did it differ from what you expected?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are having trouble, I'd start with the Sync version:

```
let serverPath = NSURL(string: "smb://yourserverpath/share")! as CFURL
let mountPath = NSURL(string: "/localmountpointyouwanttouse_shouldalreadyexist_ifnot_create_it_before")! as CFURL
let mountOptions = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: ["MountAtMountDir": false]) as CFMutableDictionaryRef
NetFSMountURLSync(serverPath, mountPath, nil, nil, nil, mountOptions, nil)
```

if you want to use the default mount point, just pass nil in there as well.

```
NetFSMountURLSync(serverPath, nil, nil, nil, nil, mountOptions, nil)
```

really it should work even if you only pass in the serverPath.  I only included the mountOptions so you have an example if you needed to set any.

```
NetFSMountURLSync(serverPath, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil)
```

The 3rd and 4th arguments are user and pass, which you can supply if you don't want the OS to handle that part.

Comment: `kNetFSMountAtMountDirKey` is a symbolic constant, a macro actually. It's not the actual key. It's defined in NetFS.h as `CFSTR("MountAtMountDir")`, so you would presumably use `"MountAtMountDir"` in Swift.

Comment: Ken is correct.  It should be: `let mountOptions = NSMutableDictionary(dictionary: ["MountAtMountDir": true]) as CFMutableDictionaryRef` if you are wanting to set these options.

Comment: @JeremyPope The code you have provided shows an error in the NSLog that says "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value", however, when I mount an SMB drive from the OS X Terminal command line, it works. Do you have any idea how did this happen?

Comment: @JeremyPope I am trying to the do the same, but I'm getting an error message "Implicit declaration of function 'NetFSMountURLSync' is invalid in C99 ", I have tried importing <objc/runtime.h> and <stdlib.h> but had no luck. Can you please help me here.

Comment: @SarimSidd you need to import NetFS in your swift file

Comment: Isn't the OP asking for an objective-c answer not swift?